# How can I pass a query string to my service in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that invokes a service like this:

```
this.resultService.getResults().subscribe(
      results => {
        this.results = results;
        this.searchResults = results.SearchResults; 
        this.searchResults = this.processResults(this.searchResults);                      
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```

The service uses HttpClient to get data from a website. Right now, I'm using a static URL in the service just for testing. But, now that I know the service works and is returning results, I'd like to pass in the query string to be used in the URL instead of it being hard coded. Is this possible? My service contains this code:

```
private resultsUrl = 'https://testingsite.com/api/orgs/search?primaryCategory=plumber&city=denver&stateProvince=CO&PageNumber=1';  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getResults(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.resultsUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Response Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = 'An error occurred: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}';
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

Comment: Which part of that are you stuck on? Note that you can pass query parameters as an object to the request methods, rather than bake them into the URL.

Comment: Yep, I'd love to pass in query parameters instead of baking it into the URL. I'll see if I can find an example of how to do that. Thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and accepted the answer below, just to get past this issue. However, I will now look into passing query parameters to be used in the request. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you need to make the service method to accept the parameter and pass the parameter to the service using **[string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**.

```
this.resultService.getResults("1234");
```

and your method will be,

```
getResults(category:string): Observable<any> {
    //form the url here
    return this.http.get<any>(this.resultsUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Response Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I greatly appreciate it. Based on knowledge I've gained, I will now look into how to pass in query parameters to be used in the request instead of having to modify the URL. Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `` and put the variable in $ like:

```
getResults(variable:string): Observable<any> {
    let url = `this.baseUrl/admin/user/${variable}` 
    return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Response Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!